# Increasing Space Between BIRT Designer Pro Bar Chart Bars

Tags: charts, bar-chart, space, birt, designer

I have a chart in BIRT Designer Pro with 7 tick marks (Su, M, Tu, W, Th, F, Sa). These tick marks form the x-axis of a bar chart. I am trying to determine how to increase the space between these tick marks and in turn how to increase the space between the bars. Basically I want to go from this [image: barchart1] to this [image: barchart2] withought changing the size of the bars, just the space between them. Any help is greatly appreciated. I should mention that I am doing the styling via scripting on the Script tab in the Edit Chart window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option to control this: Edit the chart -> Format -> General properties -> unit spacing

[image]

Comment: For me that seems to just make my bars smaller and doesn't really spread things out on the x-axis anymore than they are already. What I really want to do is add space between both them and their tick marks on the x-axis. Would you know of an option to do that? Thanks!

Comment: What is the current width of the chart element? Why don't you just increase this width property, in addition to adjust the "unit spacing" option described above to meet your needs. We can also control the width of a chart from scripts, but i don't think it is necessary in your case

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Such a simple thing to overlook :P. I have marked this answer as correct. Thanks!